# Using GROUP_CONCAT with GROUP EACH BY

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to concatenate strings using group_concat() aggregation function when grouping the records with group each by. Because group each by requires a parallelizable query I can not use order by. Can I assume that the order of the records in the table within each group will be maintained? If not, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with windowing functions. For example:

```
SELECT word, LAST(corpora) as corpora, LENGTH(LAST(corpora)) as corplen 
FROM (
SELECT word, 
GROUP_CONCAT(corpus) OVER (PARTITION BY word ORDER BY corpus_date) as corpora
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
)
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY corplen desc
```

This concatenates the names all of the shakespeare plays that contain a particular word and orders them by the date that they were written.

Comment: This is also a big problem for us. we counted on the fact that group_concat worked on the way that the records are ordered in the table. and it is working fine so far. Can you please check it further ASAP or share if there is any resolution? thanks a a lot.

Comment: What's the status on this one, as I ran into a similar issue.

Comment: This works with windowing functions... I rewrote my answer to give an example.